# Looping through JSON Lists

Tags: python, json, parsing

I am importing JSON arrays into python and am wondering what is triggering my error. I am using an ice cream example in this case.

My JSON has multiple use cases:

```
{
  "cones": 1,
  "toppings": [
    {
      "chocolate_chips": "yes",
      "cherries": 1,
      "sprinkles": "rainbow"
    },
    {
      "chocolate_chips": "yes",
      "cherries": 3,
      "sprinkles": "chocolate"
    },
    {
      "chocolate_chips": "yes",
      "cherries": 2,
      "sprinkles": "rainbow"
    }
  ],
  "whipped_cream": [
    "lots",
    "some",
    "none"
  ]
}
```

and

```
{
  "cones": 1,
  "cherries": 3,
  "chocolate_chips": "Yes",
  "sprinkles": "chocolate",
  "whipped_cream": [
    "Lots",
    "Some",
    "None"
  ]
}
```

Notice how one JSON has a list titled toppings, which contains the field chocolate chips, cherries, and sprinkles and the other doesn't contain that list at all, just the values. I am running this script trying to assign variables that will work regardless of the case, here is my code so far.

```
ice_cream = json.loads(json)

for i in ice_cream:
    if ice_cream['toppings'] is not None:
        toppings = (i.get('toppings'))
        for t in toppings:
            chocolate_chips = (t.get('chocolate_chips'))
            cherries:(t.get('cherries'))
            sprinkles:(t.get('sprinkles'))
    else: 
        chocolate_chips = (i.get('chocolate_chips'))
        cherries:(i.get('cherries'))
        sprinkles:(i.get('sprinkles'))
    cones = (i.get('cones'))
    whipped_cream = (i.get('whipped_cream'))
```

I get this error

```
list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: what's your desired output your code seems inefficient also your data example is not correct as it throws an error on `toppings = i.get('toppings')`

Comment: I'm going ot agree with Dmitry, we need more info. At least tell us what's your expected output.

Did you consider that there are 3 values 'cherries' in the first JSON and only 1 value of 'cherries' in the last JSON? How would you like to deal with that?

Comment: My desired output would be (Cones:1, Chocolate Chips: "Yes", Cherries: 1, "Sprinkles":"rainbow", "whipped cream":"Lots") and then for it to loop through and produce (Cones:1, Chocolate Chips: "Yes", Cherries: 1, "Sprinkles":"rainbow", "whipped cream":"Some") and then (Cones:1, Chocolate Chips: "Yes", Cherries: 1, "Sprinkles":"rainbow", "whipped cream":"None"). After this, it should proceed to the next list in "toppings"